# Parse.com data to PFTableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Having a difficult time pulling more than two objects from the parse.com query into a PFTableViewController.  The following code is working great for querying and displaying two items in the cell. However, in the detail view which is successfully segueing, I can pass the one of two objects to display that are seen in the original cell, but i would like to have all of the objects of the class display in the detail view controller. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to query or (maybe initiate is the right term) more than two objects from the class to have them passed into the detailViewController.
My class name is "event"
Objects I would like to pull into detailView:"category" (successful) 
But also: "createdAt" "comment" and "duration(int)"

My PFTableViewController:

```
import UIKit; import Parse

class UserRecordsTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
    override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Configure the PFQueryTableView
        self.parseClassName = "Event"
        self.textKey = "category"
        self.title = "createdAt"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false

    }

    // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "event")
        query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())


        return query
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {


        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UserRecordsTableViewCell!

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UserRecordsTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

    var dateUpdated = object.createdAt as NSDate
    var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, h:mm a"

    cell.catDate.text = NSString(format: "%@", dateFormat.stringFromDate(dateUpdated))
    cell.catTitle.text = object["category"] as String!

    return cell
    }

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as DetailUserRecordsViewController

        // Pass the selected object to the destination view controller.
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let row = Int(indexPath.row)
            detailScene.currentObject = objects[row] as? PFObject
        }
    }
}
```

My Detail View Controller

```
import UIKit
import Parse

// Container to store the view table selected object
var currentObject : PFObject?

class DetailUserRecordsViewController: UIViewController {

    // Container to store the view table selected object
    var currentObject : PFObject?

    @IBOutlet weak var eventTextAlter: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var dateTextAlter: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var durationTextAlter: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var commentTextAlter: UITextField!






    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        // Unwrap the current object object



        if let object = currentObject? {

            /*var dateUpdated = object.createdAt as NSDate
            var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormat.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, h:mm a"

            var newDuration = object["duration"] as String*/

            eventTextAlter.text = object["category"] as String
            //dateTextAlter.text = NSString(format: "%@", dateFormat.stringFromDate(dateUpdated))
            //durationTextAlter.text = newDuration as String
            //commentTextAlter.text = object["comments"] as String
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
```

Comment: Can you display what values/errors you're getting from `dateUpdated`, `newDuration`, and `object["comments"]`?

Comment: Are you certain that your `@IBOutlets` have been properly connected to their respective UI counterparts?

Comment: @IBOutlets do appear to be connected

Comment: The whole thing blows when running with those uncommented. The simulator runs, but when I press cell to segue to detail view -> lldb and tons of thread errors. Not sure how to display all of the errors on this forum.

Comment: Do you know how to use breakpoints with the debugger to step though your code? [break point tutorial](http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode) also, see the section titled "Exception Breakpoints" and enable the all exceptions breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for advice, going through one at a time. I get this for "comments": fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Try unwrapping your `object` values like you did with `currentObject`.